# How to install svn in sles 12?

Tags: svn, opensuse, suse, sles

I am trying to install svn in suse linux. I followed this guide http://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=devel:tools:scm:svn&package=subversion

I have added the repo, but still I am not able to find the package.

```
linux-pohb:~ # zypper install subverion
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'subverion' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'subverion' found.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.
```

Though it shows me the package exists:

```
linux-pohb:~ # zypper search subversion
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S | Name           | Summary                            | Type      
--+----------------+------------------------------------+-----------
  | subversion     | Subversion version control system  | srcpackage
  | subversion-doc | Documentation files for Subversion | package   
  | subversion-doc | Documentation files for Subversion | srcpackage
```

Tried yast too, but didn't find anything for svn except documentation and svni.

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are spelling subversion incorrectly. It should be "zypper install subversion" and not "zypper install subverion"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to add a the SDK to your repositories (e.g. download the DVD and add it to the local repositories or add the SUSE Repository):
https://www.suse.com/documentation/sled-12/book_sle_deployment/data/sec_add-ons_sdk.html
Then you will be able to install:

```
# zypper search subversion
Dienst 'SMT-http_smt-server' wird aktualisiert.
Daten des Repositories laden ...
Installierte Pakete lesen ...

S | Name                       | Zusammenfassung                                               | Typ       
--+----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
i | subversion                 | Subversion version control system                             | Paket     
  | subversion                 | Subversion version control system                             | Quellpaket
  | subversion-bash-completion | Bash Completion for subversion                                | Paket     
  | subversion-devel           | Development package for Subversion developers                 | Paket     
i | subversion-perl            | Allows Perl scripts to directly use Subversion repositories   | Paket     
  | subversion-python          | Allows Python scripts to directly use Subversion repositories | Paket     
  | subversion-server          | Apache server module for Subversion server                    | Paket     
  | subversion-tools           | Tools for Subversion                                          | Paket

# zypper install subversion
...
```